# Unable to locate package libopenblas-base and Package 'cython' has no installation candidate

Tags: cython

pi@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libc-ares-dev libeigen3-dev gcc gfortran python3 libgfortran5                           libatlas3-base libatlas-base-dev libopenblas-dev libopenblas-base libblas-dev                           liblapack-dev cython libatlas-base-dev openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev python3 python3-venv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package cython is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package libopenblas-base
E: Package 'cython' has no installation candidate

help me how to fix this, already odne with the update